# How do I download and install r.denoise for GRASS GIS?

Tags: raster, grass-gis, grass-7.0

I have tries multiple ways to get it as a 'add in' in Grass 7

Answer (score 4):

From the GRASS shell

```
GRASS 7.1.svn (Geol):~ > g.extension r.denoise
Fetching <r.denoise> from GRASS GIS Addons repository (be patient)...
Compiling...
Installing...
Updating addons metadata file...
Installation of <r.denoise> successfully finished
GRASS 7.1.svn (Geol):~ > r.denoise
Description:
r.denoise - denoise topographic data

Usage:
r.denoise input=string output=string [iterations=value]
   [threshold=value] [epsg=value] [--overwrite] [--help] [--verbose]
   [--quiet] [--ui]

Flags:
....
Parameters:
     input   Raster input map
    output   Denoised raster output map
iterations   Number of normal-updating iterations
           options: 1-50
           par défaut: 5
 threshold   Edge-sharpness threshold
           options: 0.0-1.0
           par défaut: 0.93
 epsg   EPSG projection code (required if current location is not projected)
```

[image]

Or from the GUI: Parameters/extension list/...[g.extension]